# Thymeleaf HTML if else in the same line

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in my Thymeleaf HTML page, I would like to know if it is possible to put and if else in the same statement

```
<div th:if="${book.htmlIconColor != null}" >
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" th:style="${'color:' + book.htmlIconColor + '; text-align: center;'}" aria-hidden="true"></i>                     
</div>
<div th:if="${book.htmlIconColor == null}" >
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x"  aria-hidden="true"></i>                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

For example

```
<i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" th:style="${book.htmlIconColor} ? 'color:' + ${book.htmlIconColor} + '; text-align: center;' : 'text-align: center;'"></i>
```